# I get error while using VR android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #44: Error inflating class com.google.vr.sdk.widgets.video.VrVideoView

Tags: java, android, mobile

I get error while using [Google VR](https://developers.google.com/vr/android/download)

As [this error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40092868/android-xml-inflateexception-google-cardboard/40759264#40759264)

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #44: Error inflating class com.google.vr.sdk.widgets.video.VrVideoView
```

This is my Layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/gorilla_info"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:id="@+id/textView" />
    <com.google.vr.sdk.widgets.video.VrVideoView
        android:id="@+id/video_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:layout_height="250dip"/>

    <!-- Seeking UI & progress indicator.-->
    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seek_bar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/status_text"
        android:text="Loading Video..."
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:paddingStart="32dp"
        android:paddingEnd="32dp"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

This is my Build.gradle (Module: app):

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.google.devrel.vrviewapp"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            ndk {
                abiFilters "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
            }
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
    compile project(':gvr-android-sdk/libraries:common')
    compile project(':gvr-android-sdk/libraries:commonwidget')
    compile project(':gvr-android-sdk/libraries:panowidget')
    compile project(':gvr-android-sdk/libraries:videowidget')
    compile 'com.google.protobuf.nano:protobuf-javanano:3.0.0-alpha-7'
}
```

It's failed on first line of onCreateView() method

```
 View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gorilla_fragment, container,false);


     @Nullable
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gorilla_fragment, container,false);
            seekBar = (SeekBar) view.findViewById(R.id.seek_bar);
            statusText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.status_text);
            videoWidgetView = (VrVideoView) view.findViewById(R.id.video_view);
}
```

It's failed on all virtual devices and Real Devices.

What's the problem?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found resolution to my problem.
in order to fix the error, i should add

```
'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:r1.5.10'
```

to Build.gradle (Module: app):

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
    compile project(':gvr-android-sdk/libraries:common')
    compile project(':gvr-android-sdk/libraries:commonwidget')
    compile project(':gvr-android-sdk/libraries:panowidget')
    compile project(':gvr-android-sdk/libraries:videowidget')
    compile 'com.google.protobuf.nano:protobuf-javanano:3.0.0-alpha-7'
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem. Resolve by move to like that on Build.gradle

```
def vrVersion = "1.180.0"

dependencies {

    implementation "com.google.vr:sdk-base:$vrVersion"
    implementation "com.google.vr:sdk-audio:$vrVersion"
    implementation "com.google.vr:sdk-common:$vrVersion"
    implementation "com.google.vr:sdk-commonwidget:$vrVersion"
    implementation "com.google.vr:sdk-panowidget:$vrVersion"
    implementation "com.google.vr:sdk-videowidget:$vrVersion"
}
```